# Is there a specific historical figure or era that is most responsible for our current definitions of "physical change" and "chemical change"?

Tags: history-of-chemistry

I understand that there is a very blurred distinction between the idea of a physical and a chemical change at advanced levels of chemistry, so I'm referring mainly to the definitions provided in most introductory texts and websites:

- physical change - processes that change the form of a substance and not its chemical composition.
- chemical change - processes in which new substances are created through changes to a substance's chemical composition.

The closest thing I found to an answer is the formation of Dalton's atomic theory in the early 19th century, which defines a chemical reaction as a rearrangement of atoms in the reactant and product compounds. I am hoping to confirm that this is the earliest definition closest to our modern perception of physical and chemical change, and that I am not missing anybody important.

Comment: Why "blurred"? The distinction is very clear also in advanced modern natural science, and based on distinct changes in the electronic structure of materials (excluding phase transitions). Physicists can also handle a test tube, chemists do a lot of physics.

Comment: @Karl Shame on you that new user gets it better ;)  @ OP. It's not "blurred at advanced levels of chemistry" but non-existent. Also there's hardly any such "current definition". Write the source of what you cite and the one who wrote the source has made the "definition".

Comment: Consider also the SE site [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).